# Why do I get this python kivy error: CRITICAL] [App ] Unable to get a Window, abort?

Tags: python, pip, kivy

I am trying to make a basic hello world program in kivy using python but I am still getting this error: **[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.**

I have installed kivy using pip with these commands:

python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools

python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew -> (when installing this I also got that: WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip)

python -m pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer

python -m pip install kivy.deps.angle

python -m pip install kivy

**This is the full error:**

[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users.kivy\logs\kivy_21-08-19_60.txt

[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.3.2

[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.0

[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.0

[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.3.1

[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0

[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at
"C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\kivy_*init*_.py"

[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:48:03) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]

[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe"

[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded

[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pil (img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer ignored)

[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pil(['text_sdl2'] ignored)

[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing *window_sdl2: The specified module could not be found.
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\kivy\core_*init**.py", line 58, in core_select_lib
mod = **import**(name='{2}.{0}.{1}'.format(
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 27, in 
from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.

**And this is my code:**

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

kivy.require('2.0.0')  

# Defining a class
class MyFirstKivyApp(App):
    
    def build(self):
        return Label(text ="Hello World !")          
  
MyFirstKivyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use conda then it must be a dependency probelm. Unistall kivy and then install it using conda (Not pip) if that didn't work then install kivy using a virtual environment. The latter method will work for sure but if you don't want that you work on a virtual environment than you can copy the folder kivy to your enviroment and replace it along with share folder.